# I have tried to bind my Tkinter button to the Enter key on the keyboard but it is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

my code is:

```
def check(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, Age_Entry, Phone_Entry, event = None):
    FName = FName_Entry.get()
    LName = LName_Entry.get()
    Age = Age_Entry.get()
    Number = Phone_Entry.get()
    length = len(Phone_Entry.get())
    if not FName.isalpha():
        errormsg = Message(root, text='Enter a valid first name', anchor=CENTER, bg = "red", width = 1000)
        canvas.create_window(1020, 134, anchor=NW, window=errormsg)
        # messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Only letters are allowed!')
```

this goes on -

```
def Per_Form():
.
.
Next_button = Button(root, text="Next", anchor=CENTER, command=lambda: check(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, Age_Entry, Phone_Entry))
    Next_button.configure(width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", border=10)
    canvas.create_window(920, 450, anchor=NW, window=Next_button)
    Next_button.bind("<Return>", check)
```

I checked out many websites and stack overflow pages too there are just so many ways to do this that I am confused which one to use and most that I tried don't work.

I have tried to bind my `Next_button` to the `check` function and the Enter key on the keyboard but it is not working and I still have to use the mouse to click on the button - what do I do?

Comment: Where are you expecting all of those parameters to `check()` to come from?  When a function is called via an event binding, it receives exactly one parameter (the event itself, which isn't really useful to you in this situation).

Comment: @jasonharper so how can I fix this now?

Comment: You could fix it in much the same way that you made the Button's `command=` option work: bind to a lambda that takes one parameter (that you ignore), and calls `check()` with all the parameters it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provide all the necessary parameters while you bind the Button to Enter-Event
Try this:

```
Next_button.bind("<Return>", lamnda event: check(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, Age_Entry, Phone_Entry))
```

Comment: How about the check function? Should it be this:                                                      def check(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, Age_Entry, Phone_Entry, event = None):

Comment: Yes, you can define it the way you want, But whichever parameters are there in function you have to provide them while you bind the function to event

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the focus is on the NextButton When you press -Enter, You can reach button by pressing TAB Button repeatedly.
Button with Focus looks like the one in the attached Snip.

[image]

Comment: oh never mind, I was being dumb - that does work thank you!!